# InvalidPathException Illegal char error

Tags: android

My app builds fine, but I get this below error trying to run `Lint` on my project.
`Android Studio 2.3` and `Windows 10`:

```
InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 9: sdk.dir=C:\Users\NICK\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem by deleting a cached file under the build/intermediates directory. Perhaps if I had gone to "File > Invalidate Caches and Restart" that may also have resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

You have the string:

```
sdk.dir=C:\Users\NICK\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository
0123456789
```

Index 9 is the semi-colon, so what you want is instead:

```
sdk.dir=file://C/Users/NICK/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository
```

The system is thinking that `C:` represents a protocol, so use `file:` to explicitly use the `file` protocol, and use the UNC name reference. Forward slashes will also help with portability.

You may also be able to get away with:

```
sdk.dir=\\C\Users\NICK\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository
```

or perhaps just:

```
sdk.dir=\Users\NICK\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository
```

If you just have the one drive.